# Unable to install new package in Kubuntu 18.04 - Media change: please insert the disc labeled…

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu

I have just installed Kubuntu 18.04 and as soon as I try to install a new package it always shows this message:

```
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the *Software & Updates* application, select the *Ubuntu Software* tab, and uncheck the *Cdrom* option the is marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot. You will need to type your user password in order to authenticate any changes in Software & Updates. Also make sure that you have marked the first four options under the *Ubuntu Software* tab.

   [image]
2. Select the *Other Software* tab, and uncheck the *Cdrom* option that is highlighted in the below screenshot. You will need to type your user password in order to authenticate any  changes in Software & Updates.

   [image]
3. Close the Software & Updates window, open the terminal, and run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software.
4. Now you can install new packages without getting an `Media change: please insert the disc labeled` error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this on Debian installs (never an Ubuntu derivative). The solution in my Debian cases is to edit (as superuser--back up the file, be careful, etc., etc.) the file /etc/apt/sources.list and comment out a line beginning with something like "deb cdrom", and add URLs for online repositories.

Okay...quick check, and you're not the only person to run into this. Here: https://vninja.net/2018/10/08/ubuntu-18.04.1-lts-bionic-beaver-sources.list/ you can find some instructions for restoring a "normal" Kubuntu sources.list file (the webpage I've linked, in turn uses this sources.list file: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/h0bbel/4b28ede18d65c3527b11b12fa36aa8d1/raw/a4ab1c13a92171822215143b1e3b3eb6add7a78d/sources.list)

Comment: Yes I have commented out the line , but it shows now that package build essentials is obsolete.

Comment: And also after adding the repositories url , apt update returns that you cannot add repositories as this feature is disabled by default , any way to enable that ?

Comment: I tried installing Kubuntu 18.04.1 in a VM to see if I could replicate your problem. The installation gave me a good sources.list, so that wasn't a problem for me, but I moved it and tried the instructions I linked to anyway. It worked on my installation. I did a minimal install and accepted all default options. If you're in a situation where you can easily reinstall, I'd recommend doing that, possibly try a more recent ISO (18.04.2 is available).

Comment: Please keep us up to date, by editing your question. Show us what you have done, and what happened.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the cdrom entry from the sources.list file. Just run:

```
sudo sed -i '/cdrom/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Removing the `cdrom` sources have already been mentioned in older answers.